# How to format date in Logstash Configuration

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I am using logstash to parse log entries from an input log file.

**LogLine:**

```
TID: [0] [] [2016-05-30 23:02:02,602]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} -  Configured Registry in 572ms {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService}
```

**Grok Pattern:**

```
TID:%{SPACE}\[%{INT:SourceSystemId}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:ProcessName}\]%{SPACE}\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:TimeStamp}\]%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:MessageType}%{SPACE}{%{JAVACLASS:MessageTitle}}%{SPACE}-%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:Message}
```

My grok pattern is working fine. I am sending these parse entries to an rest base api made by myself.

**Configurations:**

```
output {
    stdout { }
     http {
        url => "http://localhost:8086/messages"
        http_method => "post"
        format => "json"
        mapping => ["TimeStamp","%{TimeStamp}","CorrelationId","986565","Severity","NORMAL","MessageType","%{MessageType}","MessageTitle","%{MessageTitle}","Message","%{Message}"]
    }
}
```

In the current output, I am getting the date as it is parsed from the logs:

**Current Output:**

```
{ 
"TimeStamp": "2016-05-30 23:02:02,602"
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

But the problem is that my API is not expecting the date in such format, it is expecting the date in generic xsd type i.e datetime format. Also, as mentioned below:

**Expected Output:**

```
{ 
"TimeStamp": "2016-05-30T23:02:02:602"
}
```

Can somebody please guide me, what changes I have to add in my filter or output mapping to achieve this goal.

Comment: Are you sure about `2016-05-30T23:02:02:602`? Shouldn't it be `2016-05-30T23:02:02.602` , i.e. with a period before the milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to transform

```
2016-05-30 23:02:02,602
```

to the XSD datetime format

```
2016-05-30T23:02:02.602
```

you can simply add a [`mutate/gsub` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub) in order to replace the space character with a `T` and the `,` with a `.`

```
filter {
  mutate {
    gsub => [
      "TimeStamp", "\s", "T",
      "TimeStamp", ",", "."
    ]
  }
}
```